# pyodbc - [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Tags: pyodbc

I am setting up a system to connect to an AWS Redshift database from python. I am thinking that there's something wrong in the python script because I can connect via isql. I've installed all the relevant packages, and I am able to connect via isql as follows:

```
$ isql rndredshift readonly ***** -v
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> quit
```

However, my python script is failing to connect. Here's the script:

```
import pyodbc
import sys

def main():
   redshift_conn_str = assemble_connection_string(
        Driver='{PostgreSQL}',
        Server='10.191.4.97',
        ServerName='rndredshift',
        Port='5439',
        Database='prod',
        Uid='readonly',
        Pwd='*******'
    )
    print("===========")
    print(redshift_conn_str)
    print("===========")
    new_conn2 = pyodbc.connect(redshift_conn_str)
    print(psql.read_sql('select top 10 * from rawdb.raw_imprequest_20150101', new_conn2))

def assemble_connection_string(**kwargs):
    return ';'.join([k + '=' + v for (k, v) in kwargs.items()])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Here's the output:

```
===========
Uid=readonly;Database=prod;ServerName=rndredshift;Driver={PostgreSQL};  Server=10.191.4.97;Pwd=********;Port=5439
===========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_redshift.py", line 24, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "test_redshift.py", line 17, in main
    new_conn2 = pyodbc.connect(redshift_conn_str)
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

The PosgreSQL driver is installed:

```
$ odbcinst -q -d
[PostgreSQL]
[MySQL]
```

And the data source is configured:

```
$ odbcinst -q -s
[rndredshift]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DSNs, you're going to need to specify that in your connection string. Also, if you want to use DSN-less connections, I believe the keyword is SERVER and not SERVERNAME.

Try this connection string?

```
Uid=readonly;Database=prod;DSN=rndredshift;Driver={PostgreSQL};Pwd=********;
```

Make sure you specify the full server name and port in odbc.ini as well. Also, since you're using PostgreSQL, any reason you're not using the native PostgreSQL driver?

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Also, I've been perplexed over the ways to obtain and install the PostgreSQL driver. When I installed unixODBC, the odbcinst.ini file was created and contained an entry for the PostgreSQL driver that looked this this:

```
[PostgreSQL]
Description     = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/psqlodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage       = 1
```

However, the files for Driver and Driver64 where not on the system. So then, I installed postgresql-odbc, which gave me the missing libraries. Is there a better way to do this? As I mentioned earlier, isql works fine, so I'm still thinking it's a python issue.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try using the psycopg2 package, and I got a connection to work! Here's my script:

```
import sys
import psycopg2

def main():

    conn_string = "host='10.191.4.97' dbname='prod' user='readonly' password='****' port='5439'"
    print("===========")
    print(conn_string)
    print("===========")
    new_conn2 = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    print("Connected using psycopg2!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

So, while I'm happy that I can connect, the question still remains about pyodbc and the PostgreSQL connection string. Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Here's the connection string:
    Uid=readonly;Database=prod;ServerName=rndredshift;Driver={PostgreSQL};  Server=10.191.4.97;Pwd=********;Port=5439

Using DSN instead of ServerName didn't work.